# send sms to phone numbers from contact list

Tags: android, sms, message, android-contacts

i am try to send sms after fetching contacts from the phone book. My message is fixed(that is have to send) but the number depends on the users choice.

```
String smsNumber =    " "  ;
                String smsText = "Hello Please";

                Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + smsNumber);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
                intent.putExtra("sms_body", smsText);

                startActivity(intent);
```

I am using this, but how do i send sms to the selected person/persons  .

```
public class ContactList extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private ArrayList<contact> contact_list = null;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog = null;
    private contactAdapter mContactAdapter = null;
    private Runnable mViewcontacts = null;

    private ArrayList<contact> items;
    boolean[] isChecked;
    Cursor mCursor;
    ListView lv;
    Button b_alert;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);







        contact_list = new ArrayList<contact>();
        lv = getListView();

        mViewcontacts = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                getContacts();
            }
        };

        Thread thread = new Thread(null, mViewcontacts, "ContactReadBackground");
        thread.start();
        mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(ContactList.this,
                "Please Wait...", "Retriving Contacts...", true);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private void getContacts() {

        try {

            String[] projection = new String[] {
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts._ID };

            mCursor = managedQuery(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                    projection, ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER
                            + "=?", new String[] { "1" },
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);

            while (mCursor.moveToNext()) {
                contact contact = new contact();

                String contactId = mCursor.getString(mCursor
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                contact.setContactName(mCursor.getString(mCursor
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)));
                contact_list.add(contact);
            }
            isChecked = new boolean[mCursor.getCount()];

            for (int i = 0; i < isChecked.length; i++) {
                isChecked[i] = false;
            }

            this.mContactAdapter = new contactAdapter(this, R.layout.listview,
                    contact_list);
            lv.setAdapter(this.mContactAdapter);
            mCursor.close();

            runOnUiThread(returnRes);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("getContacts", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public class contactAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<contact> {

        public contactAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                ArrayList<contact> items1) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, items1);
            items = items1;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder mViewHolder;

            mViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.listview, parent, false);
            mViewHolder.cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

            convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);

            if (isChecked[position] == true)
                mViewHolder.cb.setChecked(true);
            else
                mViewHolder.cb.setChecked(false);
            mViewHolder.cb
                    .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                boolean ischecked) {
                            if (buttonView.isChecked())
                                isChecked[position] = true;
                            else
                                isChecked[position] = false;
                        }
                    });

            contact contacts = items.get(position);
            if (contacts != null) {
                if (mViewHolder.cb != null) {
                    mViewHolder.cb.setText(contacts.getContactName());
                }
            }

            return convertView;
        }
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        CheckBox cb;
    }

    private Runnable returnRes = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (mProgressDialog.isShowing())
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            mContactAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }
    };

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "Check out this photo:it's via abc:https://www.abc.com/"); 
            sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
            sendIntent.putExtra("address",_phoneNo);//here phoneno is String that contain phone no
            startActivity(sendIntent);
```